# Generate all strings within a given Hamming distance

Tags: c++, string, hamming-distance

I'm looking for an efficient `C++` function that given a `string` (of a given alphabet that happens to be: A,C,G,T,N) will generate all sequences that are at a certain Hamming distance from it. Ideally, the output will be a map with `key` as each of these strings and the `value` as the input string.

Is there such an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The number of sequences depends on the length of original sequence and the hamming distance. If hamming distance is one, you could just scan through the sequence and change the character in every position.